# "Module not found" while trying to debug with VSC a remote deployed containerized Django app

Tags: python, django, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a django app inside a container that is deployed in a remote server. I have successfully set up VSC in order to debug my app. I have started debugging my django app but I get the error ModuleNotFound while debugging.

[image]

Obviously, since the django app is deployed and working perfectly, all requirements modules do exists. Despite that, I get this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to choose your python interpreter with installed Django.

Usually it placed on `\venv\Scripts\bin\python`

[image]

Comment: I need to know your OS and package manager to answer more correctly

Comment: my local machine is windows 10 and the remote is Ubuntu. My package manager is pip

Comment: @A.Ktns Do you create virtualenvs using python -m venv venv?

Comment: Actually you were right! I had to select a different interpreter! Thank you !